# PHPUnit ZF2 InputFilter with Custom Validator

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I have the following InputFilter:

```
<?php

namespace Login\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

/**
 * Class Login
 *
 * @package Login\InputFilter
 */
class Login extends InputFilter
{
    /**
     * Construct
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        /**
         * Password
         */
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'password',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'stringtrim'
                    ]
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'                   => 'stringlength',
                        'options'                => [
                            'min' => '5',
                            'max' => '128'
                        ],
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'                   => 'regex',
                        'options'                => [
                            'pattern' => '/^[^\\\' ]+$/'
                        ],
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Init
     */
    public function init()
    {
        /**
         * Employee ID
         */
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'employeeId',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'stringtrim'
                    ]
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'                   => 'stringlength',
                        'options'                => [
                            'min' => '1',
                            'max' => '20'
                        ],
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'                   => 'digits',
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'                   => 'Login\Validator\EmployeeId',
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Attached to the `employeeId` is a custom validator I've created to check if the Employee ID actually exists in a database. It has a constructor for Doctrine Entity Manager. This works fine when testing via the web, so no worries there.

However now I would like to test via `PHPUnit` and I've created the following test:

```
<?php

namespace LoginTest\InputFilter;

use Login\InputFilter\Login;

/**
 * Class LoginTest
 *
 * @package LoginTest\InputFilter
 */
class LoginTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Login $inputFilter
     */
    protected $inputFilter;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->inputFilter = new Login();

        $this->inputFilter->init();

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testFormHasElements()
    {
        $inputs = $this->inputFilter->getInputs();

        $this->assertArrayHasKey(
            'employeeId',
            $inputs
        );

        $this->assertArrayHasKey(
            'password',
            $inputs
        );
    }
}
```

When the test runs the following error is produced:

```
1) LoginTest\InputFilter\LoginTest::testFormHasElements
Argument 1 passed to Login\Validator\EmployeeId::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /vhosts/admin-application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 180 and defined
```

I'm not certain how I can get passed this particular error. I assume I need to use Mockery but I'm not certain.

The validator has a Factory which supplies the Doctrine Entity Manager from the Service Locator.

I am still very new to PHPUnit but I've been trying to do my research before asking here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because you directly instantiate you input filter and it isn't then aware of your custom validator factory.

In real application InputFilter is using [`Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/ValidatorPluginManager.php) for getting validators from service manager.

I see two ways how to solve this problem:

1.) You can setup real service manager from application configuration, like it's described in [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html) and then pull the input filter from service manager:

```php
$inputFilter = Bootstrap::getServiceManager()->get(\Login\InputFilter\Login::class); // change the service name if you have another
```

This solution is good if you want to write some kind of integration tests.

2.) You can mock your custom validator and inject into `ValidatorPluginManager` in setup method:

```php
protected function setUp()
{
    $validator = $this->getMockBuilder(\Login\Validator\EmployeeId::class)->getMock();

    $inputFilter = new Login();
    $inputFilter->getFactory()
        ->getDefaultValidatorChain()
        ->getPluginManager()
        ->setService(\Login\Validator\EmployeeId::class, $validator);
    $inputFilter->init();

    $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;

    parent::setUp();
}
```

This solution is good if you want to write unit tests for Login input filter.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. What you mentioned made a lot of sense and it put me back on track. The only thing I added to your example was the $validator needed to have `->disableOriginalConstructor()` for the mocked object